# How to specify a different user when publishing to a topic with SNS in Python?

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

When I try to publish to a topic in my terminal:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('sns', region_name="us-east-2")
response = client.publish(
    TopicArn="my_topic_arn",
    Message="message",
)
```

I get this
`user/xxxxx is not authorized to perform: SNS:Publish on resource:`

How can I change it to use `user/yyyyy`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`user/xxxxx` is the one you have configured AWS Credentials with using default profile. If you want to use `user/yyyyy` credentials you will need to update AWS Credentials using `aws configure` or setting them in environment variables `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`